# Problems trying to assign **varname to *varname[]. c++

Tags: c++

In my .h, I have a variable, `Texture ** skyboxTextures`. I assign some texture pointers in one method, and use them right away:

```
Texture *skt[] = { 
    tleft,
    tright,
    tfront,
    tback,
    tup,
    tdown
};
skyboxTextures = skt;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    skyboxTextures[i]->load();
}
```

Then later in another method I try to use the textures again.

```
Texture *skt[] = skyboxTextures;

// Render the front quad
skyboxTextures[0]->activate();
```

This is my issue I cannot access my objects any more. This will not compile because of this error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Texture **' to 'Texture *[]'
```

If I comment out the line `Texture *skt[] = skyboxTextures;`, all I get are invalid texture pointers.

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do?

Comment: @Piotr Blow up... guess which planet.

Comment: skyboxTextures is an array of 6 texture pointers so my skybox object knows how to draw itself. The first use textures is when I read in the texture filenames when I load my map. The second use is activating the texture so when I draw my skybox it's filled in with the right texture image.

Comment: No, skyboxTextures is not an array, it is a Texture pointer pointer. Pointers are not arrays. You'll probably get better answers if you post more context around the definition of `skt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then later in another method I try to use the textures again.

You cannot do that. Converting an array into a pointer to it's first element is a one way process. While the array is still an array the compiler has information like the size of the array available at compile time. Once it's a pointer, the compiler no longer has that information.

You either have to reference `skt` itself, or just not convert `skyboxTextures` back to an array at all. `skyboxTextures[0]->activate();` should work just as you would expect.

> If I comment out the line Texture *skt[] = skyboxTextures;, all I get are invalid texture pointers.

My guess is that the issue lies here:

```
Texture *skt[] = { 
    tleft,
    tright,
    tfront,
    tback,
    tup,
    tdown
};
```

You must ensure tleft, tright, tfront, tback, tup, and tdown are valid when you use the other array. If you did something like allocated them on the stack and then returned `skyboxTextures` as a pointer from your method then you'd have undefined behavior. You'll probably have to put these on a heap allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign arrays.  Unfortunately, it's difficult to know exactly what to suggest, as you've only provided a small snippet of your code.  I would recommend reading this, however: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Teal,

Try updating this line 
  Texture *skt[] = skyboxTextures;

to
  Texture **skt = skyboxTextures;

Comment: but beats me why would you want to Texture** to Texture*[].

Comment: If it's an array you could use things like `sizeof()`.